LoginPath not getting called on Authentication
I am using AddAuthentication and AddCookie in a very standard fashion (like described on this blog https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-cookie-authentication/), and every aspect of it is working, except that if I specify a LoginPath, it is never called.  Instead, the application goes directly to my configured OpenIdConnect single sign on site if the user is not authenticated and accesses a route with an AuthorizeFilter.  I really want to manually do some things before going to the SSO site, though.  What could I be missing that is preventing the LoginPath from getting used?
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("SecondaryScheme")
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
 
            });

In my Owin application I could control this behavior by setting AuthenticationMode to Passive, as opposed to Active, but I cannot find a similar option in .Net Core.

Please edit your question and provide a minimal, reproduceable example of the problem as text within your post. Links are ok only if they're secondary / support material -- your question must be able to stand on its own if that link were to stop working, and also so people who can't access the link can still understand your question.

I finally figured it out.  I was setting the default scheme to one of my OpenIdConnect schemes.  Once I set the default scheme to "Cookies", which is the scheme managed by AddCookie, LoginPath started getting respected.
